# EOFError using numpy.load()

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pickle

I have a command to load data from a npy file:

```
utable = numpy.load('utable.npy')
```

But this results in EOFError:

```
File "/home/divyat/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 419, in load
    pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
  File "/home/divyat/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 640, in read_array
    array = pickle.load(fp, **pickle_kwargs)
EOFError
```

I don't understand the error.  What is happening exactly?  The numpy.load() method calls a pickle.load() function, which causes error. The file utable.npy is a file used for generating text embeddings using skipthoughts. I downloaded the files from here:

https://github.com/ryankiros/skip-thoughts#getting-started

Comment: Are you sure `utable.npy` is not empty?

Comment: Yes, its not empty. Its size is 1.2 GB

Comment: Did you get any solution to this problem? I am facing the same issue and I can see the binary value when debugging but it gives EOFError when using pickle.loads

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the pickled file that you are trying to load does not support readline() method.
Check wether the .npy file is created in your default director...